# How to seperate bash current path line into 2 lines in ZSH installed terminal?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Here in the terminal `ZSH is in use` the command showing the current path is like this.

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu  ~/Desktop/FolderName/FolderName1/FolderName2/FolderName3/FolderName4~
```

But when working in large nested directories the line is getting lengthy and occupying large place. So i wanted to seperate this into 2 lines where first line having the path of the current folder and the second line showing the ~ like this.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu  ~/Desktop/FolderName//FolderName1/FolderName2/FolderName3/FolderName4
~
```

At the second line we can enter the command.

Answer (score 1):

In your .bashrc, you must introduce a '**\n**' where you want to back to the line.

Extract of my .bashrc (final line) :

```
# Define color variables
Color_Off='\[\033[0m\]'         # Text Reset

# Bold
BRed='\[\033[1;31m\]'     # Red
BBlue='\[\033[1;34m\]'    # Blue
BWhite='\[\033[1;37m\]'   # White

# Setup Bash prompt
shopt -s checkwinsize

if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
    base_color="${BRed}"
else
    base_color="${BBlue}"
fi

PS1="${base_color}|=[${BWhite}\j${base_color}]==[${BWhite}\t${base_color}]===[${BWhite}\u${base_color}@${BWhite}\h${base_color}]====[${BWhite}\w${base_color}]${Color_Off}"
PS1="${PS1}\n${base_color}|=====${BWhite}>>${Color_Off} "
```

Comment: Iam using zsh in my terminal , if i use this will this break any stuff on zsh.

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't know how that work with zsh. Don't copy all extract, just put '\n' where do you want in your to test.

Comment: If you are using `zsh`, then your question should be tagged `zsh`, not `bash`. `.bash_profile` will not be relevant either.

Comment: I tried using the last line and it eventually broke.

Comment: Look this link, thos can help you :

Comment: Other solution : in your .zshrc, change the parameter 'ZSH_THEME'.

Comment: this site list few theme : [link](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes)

Answer (score 0):

Your current prompt looks something like this:

```
PS1='%n@%m %d%~'
```

To introduce a newline, use `$'\n'`:

```
PS1=$'%n@%m %d\n%~'
```

You might also want to consider showing only part of the current working directory:

```
PS1='%n@%m %3d%~'
```

which would show at most 3 trailing directories instead

```
ubuntu@ubuntu  FolderName2/FolderName3/FolderName4~
```

Comment: Will this be included in ~/.zshrc file ??

Comment: Most likely. Check if `PS1` (or  `PROMPT` or `prompt`, `zsh` aliases for `PS1`) is defined in `.zshrc` already.

Comment: I am including my .zshrc file here https://gist.github.com/uppusaikiran/68ccff3c87e473d253473c43bf868e86

Comment: If you are using oh-my-zsh, you'll need someone else to advise you. I used it briefly, but found it easier to just copy useful definitions into my own configuration files. I don't really recall its method for managing prompts.

Answer (score 0):

I just passed through this problem using zsh myself, and the answer couldn't be simpler, just hit enter on the keyboard while editing the your zsh PS1, here's my PS1 in my .zshrc

```
PS1="%n in %2d
~> "
```

It displays the following result in my shell.

```
neo in /home/neo
~>
```

Well, where it says neo, it really shows the user, but I put mine just an example, I hope I helped you.